# Weird ::before "margin" on Flaticon UIcons

Tags: html, css

I am currently using Flaticon's UIcons (using CDN) and I have this weird ::before margin thing. Here are some screenshots:

[image] [image]

Because of this, I can't vertically align my icons properly and it looks weird when there is text next to the icon.

I have used other icons before like fontawesome and never experienced a similar issue.

Like I said I have tried some things like adding `font-side: 0;` to the parent container but nothing worked.

I tried removing padding and margin from the icon itself too (also tried removing it from the ::before) but it doesn't always work. (for ex. when there is padding or margin on the parent).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501042/why-font-awesome-icons-have-weird-margin-on-top-when-using-small-font-sizes) is not the  same issue. I have tried the suggested solutions there and nothing worked.

Comment: So what is your question? How to remove [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo-element?

Comment: Change it to be `display: inline-flex` instead of `display: inline-block`

Comment: Anything for the margin to be gone ig. @VisioN

Comment: Didn't work @Simp4Code

Comment: @Krzheski can you provide a link or a working sample?

Comment: here @Simp4Code https://jsfiddle.net/Krzheski/hfdqxL12/

Comment: @Krzheski I've posted an answer which fixes it, it needed inline-flex but I also referenced FontAwesome to see how they did it then tweaked the values slightly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing FontAwesome with the `line-height` and `vertical-align` and then adding `display: inline-flex;` so the ::before sits in the right place

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

#fixed {
  line-height: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: -0.15em;
  
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn-uicons.flaticon.com/uicons-regular-rounded/css/uicons-regular-rounded.css'>

<h1>
<i class="fi fi-rr-hastag"></i> Not Aligned
</h1>

<h1>
<i id="fixed" class="fi fi-rr-hastag"></i> Aligned
</h1>
```